# Upload file and Insert DB in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have some question about Laravel 5

1. I tested upload file at localhost and homestead, it's worked, but when I tested on VPS, it's always wrong like:

> FileNotFoundException in File.php line 37:
>
> The file "/tmp/xxx" does not exist.

Why have it wrong? What is configuration I need for my wrong?

2. When I inserted data at column with type: `longtext`. if a text have a sympol (like ❤), it will be stop at this symbol and text after symbol is not insert to DB.

Sorry my English so bad, please help me :(

Comment: Please provide a code from `File.php`, otherwise it's impossible to know what might be wrong. Though, I suppose, may be in `File.php` you try to work only with existing file, instead of creating new file if it doesn't exist, e.g. trying to read a file before it was created.

Comment: `File.php` in `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/File/File.php` on [Github](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/File/File.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's Sloved !

1. Chown dir www to www-data:www-data

   sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
2. It my fault :D

thank you.